# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true": Sonar

Tags: java, session, compiler-errors, sonarqube, runtime-error

```
Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        /*
          *
         */
        try {
            session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            /*
             *
             */
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    finally {
                if(session!=null)
                    session.close();
            }
```

Sonar is giving error in the If block (if(session!=null)) that Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true". How to solve this???

Comment: I see another problem: what if the session creation fails? Then tx is null and the catch block fails.

Comment: then how to solve this?